# Building an array of promises for Promise.all() on the fly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

so I've been trying to use the `Promise.all()` method and I'm running into an issue where I need to pass the method an array of promises, but I'm not sure how many promises are going to be called for/needed by the application.

Here's a method that I've gotten working by specifically building the array

```
router.post('/test1', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Hit on POST /test1');
    let arr = ['email1@email.com','email2@email.com'];
    Promise.all([
      lookUpUserId(arr[0]),
      lookUpUserId(arr[1])
    ]).then((x)=>{res.send(x)});
});
```

My `lookUpUserId()` function is returning a promise and I'm able to use it if I explicitly list them in the array. However I've tried a few methods of creating this array on the fly and I can't seem to get it working.
Example #1

```
router.post('/test1', (req,res,next) => {
    console.log('Hit on POST /test1');
    let arr = ['email1@email.com','email2@email.com'];
    Promise.all((arr)=>{
      let out = [];
      for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        out.push(lookUpUserId(arr[i]));
      }
      return out;
    }).then((x)=>{res.send(x)});
});
```

Example 2

```
outer.post('/test1', (req,res,next) => {
    console.log('Hit on POST /test1');
    let arr = ['email1@email.com','email2@email.com'];
    let promArr = (arr)=>{
      let out = [];
      for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        out.push(lookUpUserId(arr[i]));
      }
    }
    Promise.all(promArr).then((x)=>{res.send(x)});
});
```

Comment: You've created an array-returning function, not an array.

Comment: I've cleared a whole bunch of heated comments here. Don't continue posting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()` where the first parameter to `lookUpUserId` function is expected to be an element of `arr`

```
router.post('/test1', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Hit on POST /test1');
    let arr = ['email1@email.com','email2@email.com'];
    Promise.all(arr.map(lookUpUserId))
    .then(x => res.send(x));
});
```

The issue with second approach is that you do not call the function, pass the array as parameter to the function, or return the `out` array from the function

```
outer.post('/test1', (req,res,next) => {
    console.log('Hit on POST /test1');
    let arr = ['email1@email.com','email2@email.com'];
    let promArr = arr => {
      let out = [];
      for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        out.push(lookUpUserId(arr[i]));
      }
      return out // `return` the array of `Promise` objects
    }
    Promise.all(promArr(arr)).then(x => res.send(x));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the same problem in both scenarios....your not actually invoking the function call therefore you never pass the array to Promise.all.

Using the second example, purely because it's easier to demonstrate the fix, try:

```
Promise.all(promAll(arr))
    .then(...)
    .catch(...)
```